# D3 Diagram : how may i assign images inside a node

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

you can find something like below in the jsFiddle demo included in this question, and i am wondering how may I assign images into each node.

```
var graph = {
    "nodes":[
        {"name":"1","rating":90,"id":2951},
   ]
}
```

I have jsFiddle Demo in this link : http://jsfiddle.net/JSDavi/qvco2Ljy/

**Update 1 :**

```
node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.weight * 2+ 12; })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(1/d.rating); });

node.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", d=> d.url)

        //people icon's location (x,y)

        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.weight * 2+ 12; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.height * 2+ 12; })

        //people icon's size
        .attr("width", width/10)
        .attr("height", height/10);
```

The codes above is how I set the circle and images

[image]

but they never stick together.

this is my updated demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qvco2Ljy/116/

Comment: do you want to show image on mouseover ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each object, set the URL of the image:

```
{name: "1", rating: 90, id: 2951, url: "someUrl"},
```

Then, instead of appending circles, append an `image`

```
 node.append("image")
     .attr("xlink:href", d=> d.url)
     .attr("x", -width/2)
     .attr("y", -height/2)
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);
```

Where `width` and `height` are the corresponding image width and height.

PS: have in mind that I'm simply answering your question (*"how may I assign images into each node?"*). If giving up the circles is not an option for you, you'll have to use a `pattern`.

Comment: I am able to append images but i have difficulty of putting the image into the node, i mean the circle thing

Comment: Do you want the same image or a specific image to each node?

Comment: specific image please

Comment: Then, do as I said, set an specific url for each node and append the nodes as `image` elements. Update your JSfiddle, even if it doesn't work, and I'll have a look at it.